# Windows server SMB instances

Tags: windows, nic, server-message-block

Is it possible to setup 2 instances of SMB with build-in Windows SMB?
For example: folders A, B, C and D are need to be shared. Server has 2 NICs. Is it possible to do that folder A and B is accessible through first NIC; C and D accessible through 2nd NIC?

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to run multiple instances of SMB on a Windows server. Shares can not be bound to a specific nic or IP address either.